# UIScrollView an Paginator

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I thought about the possibilities in UI Design for a new app. What I want to do is:

Have three view where the user can paginate horizontally. In each of this view there is a UIScrollView (fills the whole view) where the user can scroll vertically.

How could I manage, that horizontal scroll events are managed by the Pagination and vertical scrolls are managed by the ScrollView?

I'm sorry, maybe this is kind of a "beginner-Question"...

There might be a possibility to send the different touches to different UI-Elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the 3 scroll views inside a large scroll view.

The 3 vertical scrolling views should have a content size that matches the screen's width - this will stop them scrolling horizontally and the event will pass up to the the parent scroll view to allow horizontal scrolling.

Ensure that the content size of the parent view matches the screen height so that it only scrolls horizontally.